# JPA Query to Extract HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND from date field

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am using this query

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM myEntity t where MINUTE(t.timeStamp)= 0 " +
        " AND SECOND(timeStamp)= 0 AND t.name= :name" +
        " AND t.timeStamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
Page findAllByNameHourly(@Param("name") String name,
                                         @Param("startDate") Date startDate,
                                         @Param("endDate") Date endDate,
                                         Pageable page);
```

I tried to use the EXTRACT('MINUTE', t.timeStamp) instead, but still I get an error 'could not extract ResultSet'

Is there a way to do this?.   I am basically trying to query records that have date timestamp on the hour as in 11:00:00, 12:00:00, 1:00:00 and so on.

Thanks

Comment: `FUNCTION('SECOND', t.timeStamp)`?

Comment: Tried this too .. same error.

Comment: And dumb solutions like `t.timeStamp LIKE '%00:00%'`? BTW Date is java.util.Date, and without time conditions it works?

Comment: I would expect any JPA provider to give a more informative exception message, likely in a nested exception. And also to say if it had actually executed some SQL for the query (in its LOG).

Comment: Joop pointed me to think out of the box.   His answer nailed it.   I modified his suggestion slightly to yield desired solution  function('TO_CHAR', t.timeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') LIKE '%00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joop pointed me in the right direction.  This works for me:

function('TO_CHAR', t.timeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') LIKE '%00:00'

Thanks